# Add maximum value of legend in scale_color_gradient2 (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to add maximum value in the legend in the following code

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)    
v <- melt(volcano)
ggplot(v, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#0000FF", mid = "#FFFFFF", high ="#FF0000", 
                       midpoint = median(v$value), space = "rgb", guide = "colourbar")
```

[image]

In the legend the max value displayed is 175 but the max value in data is 195.

```
> max(v)
[1] 195
```

So how do I get to display 195 on the top of the 175 in the legend?

Comment: You can add a custom range `breaks=seq(95,195,10)`

Comment: @Vova thanks. But I am looking for generic solution, I many not know the max value every time.

Comment: Why can't you do `max(v$value)`?

Comment: Than you can try `min` and `max`, like `breaks=seq(min(v$value),max(v$value),10)`. However the max value will depend on the min value, and step. If you set your `breaks=c(min(v$value),max(v$value))` it will show only min and max.

Comment: @Vova `breaks=c(min(v$value),max(v$value))` works but does not show any ticks in between. Whereas 'breaks=seq(min(v$value),max(v$value),10)' does not work, and garbles the legend.

Comment: @Vova thanks got the solution. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I could provide an alternative answer based on the base "pretty" and "pretty_breaks()" from the "scales" package.

Building from the data and example above... try using something like this:

```
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#0000FF", mid = "#FFFFFF", high ="#FF0000",                              
                          midpoint = median(v$value), space = "rgb", 
                          guide = "colourbar",
                          limits = c(min(v$value), max(v$value)),
                          breaks=pretty_breaks(n=4)(min(v$value):max(v$value)))
```

You can also pass a numerical value to pretty_breaks to determine how many breaks you desire. Depending on your data, you may need to tweak the limits parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the legend breaks manually calculating from min and max values. e.g.

```
v <- melt(volcano)
ggplot(v, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
     geom_tile() + 
     scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#0000FF", mid = "#FFFFFF", high ="#FF0000", 
                          midpoint = median(v$value), space = "rgb", 
                          guide = "colourbar",
                          breaks=seq(min(v$value),max(v$value),
                                    (max(v$value)-min(v$value))/4))
```

[image]

Thanks to @Vova and @Sameer Chavan for the leads.

> Edit:

To make it cleaner add `ceiling` to `seq`.

```
   v <- melt(volcano)
    ggplot(v, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
         geom_tile() + 
         scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#0000FF", mid = "#FFFFFF", high ="#FF0000", 
                              midpoint = median(v$value), space = "rgb", 
                              guide = "colourbar",
                              breaks=ceiling(seq(min(v$value),max(v$value),
                                        (max(v$value)-min(v$value))/4)))
```

[image]

Any other generic solutions welcome.