# R - Set scale to (min, max) on us_maps legend across different variables in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend, scale

I am using us_maps to graph outcome variables across states and time. These variables have vastly different ranges. For example, one variable ranges from 0 to 1 and another ranges from 0 to 1 million. The mins and maxes for each variable range across each year as well.

Right now, the scale of the legend changes for each year, meaning that the same color does not represent the same value across the different maps. As such, I'd like to set the limits for the legend maps to be static for the mins and maxes across all observations of a variable (i.e., **also across all years**).

I think the code I have below isn't working because it doesn't recognize the column that I'm referencing. (See Error messages below). Below is a data excerpt, but I am using more variables in the full code (otherwise I might have considered setting limits manually).

```
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(extrafont) 

Database <- read.csv(filename)

## Defining variable and label vectors 
vars <- c("var1", "var2") 
labs <- c("lab1", "lab2") 

## Looping through vars: 
for (k in seq_along(vars)) {
     for(i in 0:10) {

    print(plot_usmap(data = filter(database, year == 1910 + i*10), values = vars[k]) +
       scale_fill_continuous(
         low = "white", high = "blue", na.value="light gray", 
         label = scales::comma, 
         name = "Legend", 
         limits = c(min(database$k), max(database$k))
        ) + 
      theme(legend.position = "right") +
      labs(title = str_c(labs[k], ", ", 1910 + i*10)))
     }
     }
```

I also tried a similar solution by including the following between the scale_fill_continuous and theme arguments:

```
   scale_size_continuous(breaks = seq(range(database$k)[1], range(database$k)[2], length.out = 5))
```

For both options, the problem seems to be that R can't find the column "k" that I'm trying to reference. E.g. for the first option, the error is:

```
 Unknown or uninitialised column: `k`.
2: In min(database$k) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: `k`.
```

Related questions:
 [(1) breaks=seq(min(v$value),max(v$value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835943/add-maximum-value-of-legend-in-scale-color-gradient2-ggplot2)

[(2) scale_size_continuous(breaks = seq(range(mpg$hwy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62842840/setting-min-max-size-in-legend-in-ggplot)

[(3) scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(datas$cyl) - 1, max(datas$cyl) + 1, 1))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337387/cant-scale-a-ggplot-axis-based-on-min-and-max-values)

[(4) scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0,60))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728589/defining-the-scale-of-the-legend-for-a-plot-usmap-in-r)

Comment: `database$k` will not work as it will look for a column with name `k`. Use `database[[k]]` to get the column whose name is stored in `k`.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. I got an error when I used limits
```
 scale_fill_continuous(
         low = "yellow", high = "red", na.value="light gray", 
         label = scales::comma, 
         name = "Legend", 
         limit = c(min(database[[k]], max(database[[k]]))))

Error in seq.default(.limits[1], .limits[2], length.out = guide$nbin) : 
  'to' must be a finite number
```
With 
```
```
Also, do you know how to specify the min/max across the whole range of observations rather than just for one year?

Comment: OP, that error might be due to mispelling `database[[k]]` as `Rafabase[[k]]`.  In any case, the "to" value in that would be `max(Rafabase[[k]])`  as you have it written.  If you just type that into your console, do you get a number or `NA`?

Comment: if I put in max(database[[k]]), I do get a value in the console, but since k is defined in the loop it doesn't help much. Also sorry for the typo, I was still editing the comment when I accidentally published it.

When I try 
```
 scale_size_continuous(breaks = seq(range(database[[k]])[1], range(database[[k]])[2], length.out = 5))
```
I get the similar error: 
```
Error in seq.default(range(Rafabase[[k]])[1], range(Rafabase[[k]])[2],  : 
  'from' must be a finite number
```